# Jdbc no suitable driver found. Postgresql

Tags: java, windows, postgresql, jdbc

So I am trying to establish a connection to my postgresql database in java but I keep getting this error:
"java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"

I have seen that there are a lot of people having this issue but none of their solutions helped in my case.

Here is my program:

```
public class psql{

    static String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres";
    static Properties props = new Properties();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Connection connection = establishConnection();
    }


    private static Connection establishConnection(){

        props.setProperty("user", "userName");
        props.setProperty("password", "password");

        Connection connection = null;

        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
        } catch (SQLException e){
            System.err.println("Didnt establish connection");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return connection;
    }
}
```

I have installed the newest postgresql jdbc driver. I have it in the same folder as my java file. I run it in cmd like this:

```
javac -cp postgresql-42.2.12.jar:. psql.java
java -cp postgresql-42.2.12.jar:. psql.java
```

I have also made sure that the username, password, etc are all spelled right and I simply dont have any idea what else to do. Can anyone tell if I am missing anything?

Edit: There is no need for help anymore. I have found the solution guys. As commented by Mark Rotteveel, I needed to use ; instead of : to sepparate items on the classpath. I cant really mark the comment as an answer so I chose to edit the question. Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: Which Java version are you using (check with `java -version`)?

Comment: The filename should be `postgresql-42.2.12.jar` (`...esql` **not** `...essql`)

Comment: It looks like the problem might the name of the jar file. Are you sure its filename is `postgressql-42.2.12.jar` and not `postgresql-42.2.12.jar` (one `s` instead of two)? Also the `java` command should be passed `psql`, not `psql.java`.

Comment: I am running java 11.  also this is a typo here. in cmd I wrote it with 1 s. Still doesnt work. Also, by writing psql only instead of psql.java the cmd tells me that it cannot find the file

Comment: Please [edit] your question and fix all those typos (or better yet: copy it instead of typing it out, because for example your current code is not complete, it is missing a closing `}`).

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. However, I thought that the missing closing was not important. Since my question (or potential answer) has nothing to do with it.

Comment: You should make it as easy as possible for use to verify what you did. In any case, I copied your code, added the missing imports and ran it succesfully (or at least, it failed to connect, because I don't have PostgreSQL running on localhost). The most likely cause is that you don't actually have `postgresql-42.2.12.jar` in the current directory, or you made the same typo on the commandline as you originally had in the question. I also note that running your `java` command if I have first run `javac` will result in an error _"error: class found on application class path: psql"_.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name With Java 11 you can actually run .java files directly from `java` (as long as there is no `.class` with the same name on the classpath).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: ah, I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @Setin: this might actually be one of the rare cases where posting a screen shot of your console with the output of `ls -l` and the results of the two commands might help.

Comment: I only wish that was the case. I am 100% sure that I have the file in the current directory. I have ran the code several times in the command line (also with 1 s, not 2) so no typo there.

Comment: Are you running on Windows instead of Linux/MacOS?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it says that ls is not recognized as a command

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes. I am running windows

Comment: Then you should use `;` instead of `:` to separate items on the classpath, so `-cp postgresql-42.2.12.jar;.`

Comment: @MarkRotteveel My God! I think that worked. I didnt get any exception at least

Comment: Good to hear. The 'problem' is that `:` is a valid character in Windows paths (ie in the drive-letter), so Java was considering `postgresql-42.2.12.jar:.` as a single class path location, which obviously doesn't exist. Which is also why your use of `psql.java` worked, because there was nothing on the classpath, so it didn't see the `psql.class`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I had no idea that Window used another character. I understand it now . Thank you for the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        } catch (final ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            throw new ApplicationException("Could not load the OJDBC driver.", e1);
        }

Comment: @rhandom Explicitly loading the driver hasn't been necessary since Java 6.